# How to get vertical tab bar in Google Chrome working?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I have used Firefox for many years and really love the vertical tab tree.
Now I want to switch to Google Chrome and read they are working on a vertical tab bar too.

How can I get this to work?

PS: The vertical Tab Bar extension is not appropriate because it doesn't replace the normal tab bar.

**Edit:** installed development version *6.0.466.0 dev*.

Comment: Uhm you cant? :)

Comment: They are working on it, so it probably is not finished yet. Maybe you could try Chromium (the developer version of Chroem) to see if it has it implemented. Besides the extension I don't know of any way to do this...

Comment: @Shiki but someone did it: http://www.chromeboard.com/showthread.php?t=7522 ;)

Comment: The instructions to make that work are on that forum. I can't guarantee that it'll work for you, but it's worth a shot...

Comment: Oh sorry. Well... it's not really vertical, it's like a feature show off. Won't even worth the try.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=34509 and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using Chrome 6.0.466.0.

To enable "vertical tabs" you have to add

```
--enable-vertical-tabs
```

Right click onto a tab and select `Use side tabs`.

[image]

Comment: An screenshot would be nice

Comment: not working in 2021 :(